# Modernizer won't show the correct values

Tags: javascript, modernizr

I'm using ie10 and have had wrong values returned from modernizr from my site, it is an internal site.
It is running and to simplify things, I have it just checking the value of hsla.
There are a lot of other features that we want to see, but to debug I have stripped it down to just look at hsla.
If I go to different sample sites, "hsla" is shown as an option.
If I go to our site ex, http://www.example.com/test.htm, "no-hsla" is shown.
I have switched out the modernizr file we are using to use one from ajax.cdnjs.com and I get the same result.
I have generated a new download modernizr with just hsla in it and same result "no-hsla".
I can copy the same exact files to a server that I hit with IP http://x.x.x.x/test.htm and it works fine and show "hsla"
this is all I have in test.htm

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" class="no-js" xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="moderntest.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Are you sure that your Internet Explorer isn't going into some sort of compatibility mode for your local domain? You can check the mode settings at the top of the developer console.

Comment: Also [here is the code used to test for `hsla()` support](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/blob/master/feature-detects/css/hsla.js) - you can try it for yourself to explore why it's not detecting support. It's so simple that it's hard to imagine that it really isn't the case that your browser is not responding the way you think it should.

Comment: From tools, compatibility view settings, I don't see any sites there.  I agree it should be simple, I'm more of a back end developer and it's the first time using modernizr that another company used, but we are cleaning up the bugs.

Comment: Well if you can make a test page using that code, you could explore *why* Modernizr is getting the result it's getting. To check whether IE is in compatibility mode, look at the "Emulation" tab in the F12 Developer Tools.

Comment: it was switching to ie10 compat View and ie7 standards.  Haven't figured out why yet, but adding the line meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10,IE=9,IE=8" keeps it from switching over.  Will continue to research if this will cause us any issues.  thanks for pointing me in a direction.